# how to access header index in vue-good-table

Tags: vue.js, vue-good-table

How do you access these header's index in a grouped table?

[table_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmXTN.png)

Comment: Please add some your code so we can get more idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just found it out, the answer was just in the picture

{{props.row.vgt_id}}

Answer (score 2):

You can get column name using `props.column`. `props.column` will give you full column object so you can get index from it. `props.column.field` will give you column name **title**.

1. You can check index with `props.column.originalIndex`
2. The original **row object** can be accessed via `props.row`
3. The currently displayed table **row index** can be accessed via `props.index` .
4. The `original row index` can be accessed via `props.row.originalIndex`.
5. You can then access the **original row object** by using `rows[props.row.originalIndex]`.
6. The **column object** can be accessed via `props.column`
7. You can access the **formatted row data** (for example - formatted date) via `props.formattedRow`

For example :

```
<vue-good-table
  :columns="columns"
  :rows="rows">
  <template slot="table-row" slot-scope="props">
    <span v-if="props.column.field == 'age'">
      <span style="font-weight: bold; color: blue;">{{props.row.age}}</span> 
    </span>
    <span v-else>
      {{props.formattedRow[props.column.field]}}
    </span>
  </template>
</vue-good-table>
```

[Source](https://xaksis.github.io/vue-good-table/guide/advanced/#custom-row-template)

Comment: @JielNiñoGaid `props.column` will give you full column object so you can get index from it.

Comment: @JielNiñoGaid you can check it with `props.column.originalIndex`

Comment: thanks anyways, but the headers in the picture is not a column, it's a row... see grouped table...

Comment: if it is row, you can use `props.row.originalIndex`

Comment: @JielNiñoGaid The currently displayed table **row index** can be accessed via `props.index`

Comment: if i do props.index.. it will return 0, 1 (group1) , 0, 1 (group2), 0,1 (group 3)

if i do props.row.originalIndex, it will return 0, 1(group1),  2, 3(group2), 4, 5(group 3)

Comment: anyway it's so hilarious, i just found it out and it was just props.row.vgt_id...

Comment: i've already read that in the documentation. none of it was the answer i was looking... though it was, props.row.vgt_id

Answer (score 0):

try this:

> `{{props.row.originalIndex}}`